# Complexity of the set of models of TA

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Recall that the theory of true arithmetic $TA$ is the theory of standard model of arithmetic $\mathcal N$. I am interested in the complexity of the set of countable models of $TA$ in the lightface or boldface Borel hierarchy on $Mod(L)$ where $L$ is the language of arithmetic, i.e., the complexity of the set

$$\mathfrak{M}(TA)=\{ \mathcal A:\mathcal A\models TA, |A|=\omega\}.$$

There is a natural upper bound on the complexity of $\mathfrak{M}(TA)$. We can write down a $\Pi_\omega$ formula in $L_{\omega_1\omega}$ "axiomatizing" TA, so by Vaught $\mathfrak{M}(TA)$ is at most $\pmb \Pi^0_\omega$. But what about a lower bound? Could it be simpler? My suspicion is no but I don't know how I would go about verifying this.

Comment: One could try to use a Harrington-style workers construction to show that there is a recursive function $M$ mapping $\Pi_\omega$ formulas $\phi$ in the language of arithmetic to recursive-in-$\phi$ descriptions of structures such that $\phi$ is true in the natural numbers if and only if $M(\phi)$ is a model of $TA$.

Comment: If I understand correctly we would get as a corollary that the index set of computable models of $TA$ $I=\{ i: \varphi_i=\mathcal A\models TA\}$ is $\Pi^0_\omega$ complete. However, by Tennenbaum's theorem $I=\{i:\varphi_i\cong \mathcal N\}$ which is $\Sigma^0_2$, contradicting the above.

Comment: You are correct that the set of codes for recursive copies of the standard model of arithmetic is an arithmetically definable set.  But Harrington's construction need not produce copies of the standard model.

Comment: Dumb question from a non-logician: Aren't $Mod(L)$ and $\mathfrak M(TA)$ proper classes? There are models of every infinite cardinality, right? And even the countable models form a proper class, since the underlying set can be any set?

Comment: It should say the set of countable models, I edited the question. To formally answer this question one usually considers models where the universe is the set of natural numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of models of true arithmetic is indeed $\pmb \Pi^0_\omega$-complete under Wadge reducibility. That is, for any $\pmb \Pi^0_\omega$ set $X$ on a Polish space $Y$, there is a continuous function $f$ such that for all $y\in Y$, $y\in X$ if and only $f(Y)$ is a model of true arithmetic. Hence, $\pmb \Pi^0_\omega$ is also the lower bound of the Borel complexity of $\mathfrak M(TA)$.

This result follows from the following result which we obtained with Uri Andrews, David Gonzalez, Steffen Lempp, and Hongyu Zhu [2]:

**Theorem 1.** A first-order theory $T$ has a $\pmb \Pi^0_\omega$ complete set of models if and only if $T$ can not be axiomatized by a set of first-order sentences of bounded quantifier complexity.

Now, true arithmetic can not have an axiomatization by a set of bounded quantifier complexity as this would contradict Tarski's undefinability of truth theorem. Hence the completeness of its set of models follows.

At the core of the proof of Theorem 1 is a theorem due to Solovay (see [1, Theorem 2.5]) which is proved using machinery for iterated priority arguments such as Harrington's workers as suggested in the comments.

[1] Knight, Julia F. “True Approximations and Models of Arithmetic.” London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 1999, 255–78.

[2] Andrews, Uri, David Gonzalez, Steffen Lempp, Dino Rossegger, and Hongyu Zhu. “The Borel Complexity of the Class of Models of First-Order Theories.” Submitted for Publication, 2024. https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2402.10029.